# Single page website, SEO and Social media share buttons

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, seo, single-page-application, sammy.js

I have a singe page website, built with SammyJS as js framework and PHP for the backend, So when I reach the point of SEO I read about google Ajax crawlers, so I did the following:
1.I add the below 2 lines to my htacess file.

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
#RewriteRule ^$ /seo/index/ [R=301,L]
```

2. I create a new controller (seo) which only will display the required data(HTML) to be indexed without any CSS or js.

So if the url contains _escaped_fragment_, the web-server will redirect it to seo controller.
This solution works fine when I share using facebook, but not works among gplus, linked-in and twitter. 
also when I test how google-bot see my site, google-bot sees 301 redirect page!.

From this, I want something to work without redirect, and this require sammyJS to be worked without hash, and I can't make it works.

my question is how to make sammy js works without #! or #, taken in consider push state not supported in all browser.

any ideas guys about this case.

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe you can make SammyJS work without the hashtag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I find this way to handle seo and social media with single page applications,

Since I use Yii framework for the back-end, in the main layout file I got the parameters of the query string, So if the url contains "_escaped_fragment_", I take this variable and its value and got the result direct without including the sammyJS routers file.

so in the top of the layout file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])){
        Return the data you want using PHP only don't relay on js,
        from here you need to provide a full html page with all data.
}else{
       include your sammy js routers file.. normal case 
}
?>
```

and also you don't need any redirection from the htaccess file.

Thanks,